# How to send multiple select list options with native (non-ASP) HTML markups?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Razor generated select list with an multiple select option enabled

I'm struggling with sending it, cuz in controller my `Cars` list is empty, null.

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
@if (Model != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.CarsModels.Count(); i++)
    {
        var car = Model.CarsModels[i];
        if (...)
        {
            <option name="Manufacturer.Cars[@i].Name" value="@car" selected>@car</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option name="Manufacturer.Cars[@i].Name" value="@car">@car</option>
        }
    }
}
</select>
```

---

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
}
```

Model.CarsModels = just a list of strings.

---

Meanwhile this one works correctly, but it's an input box, not select list's option:

```
<input name="Manufacturer.Cars[0].Name" class="form-control" value="default"/>
```

Comment: `var car = Model.CarsModels[i]` => this code potentially render the fully-qualified type of `CarsModel` instead of string content. Also `new List<Car>()` may reinitialize `Model.CarsModels` when populated into view. What kind of things not working there?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto ``What kind of things not working there? ``- After clicking "submit" on form it sends a null, but when I do it like I did in my working example, then the data is sent correctly. ``This code potentially render the fully-qualified type of CarsModel instead of string content.`` Model.CarsModels = just a list of strings. ``Also new List<Car>() may reinitialize Model.CarsModels when populated into view`` EntityFramework Core probably handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you have a select, you want to pass the value of the selected option to the back-end. In other words, all you want to pass is the `unique value of the option` (e.g.: the id, name, code, etc..) not the `complex object itself`.

So in order to make your code works you need to have something like:

```
public class ManufacturerViewModel
{
    public List<string> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

---

The view:

```
<select name="Cars" multiple class="form-control">
   @if (Model != null)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < Model.CarsModels.Count(); i++)
       {
           var car = Model.CarsModels[i];
           if (...)
           {
             <option value="@car" selected>@car</option>
           }
           else
           {
              <option value="@car">@car</option>
           }
       }
   }
</select>
```